# How to pronounce eŭ

Tags: pronunciation

I don't get to hear Esperanto speech often so I am not sure how to pronounce *eŭ*. For example *Neŭtrala* or *Eŭropo*.

How do you pronounce it?

Comment: Why makes you think that *eŭ* could be anything else than the sound of *e* followed by the sound of *ŭ*?

Comment: @miĥaŭ Diphthongs have different sounds. For example 'aj' does not make the sound of 'a' followed by a 'j'

Comment: Well, I do pronounce *aj* by combining *a* and *j*. And that's correct, according to Fundamento: "Every word is to be read exactly as written, there are no silent letters". Where did you learn that it should be pronounced in some different way?

Comment: While I would disagree with Tony's thought that AJ is anything more than A+J, the original question is a legitimate question. See answers below.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Esperanto_pronunciation#Diphthongs

Comment: @Tony - I think you're splitting hairs, and two can play at the wiki game: (i̯) "The close front unrounded vowel is the vocalic equivalent of the palatal approximant [j]. The two are almost identical featurally. [...]  [i̯] with the non-syllabic diacritic and [j] are used in different transcription systems to represent the same sound." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_front_unrounded_vowel

Comment: Diphthongs make a different sound because the letters merge together. Yes. I am splitting hairs. I don't really care about this. I just care about the question being answered. But since people want to know. Here is the source: "There are also six historically stable diphthongs: /ai̯/, /oi̯/, /ui̯/, /ei̯/ and /au̯/, /eu̯/. However, some authors such as John C. Wells regard them as vowel + consonant combinations (/aj/, /oj/, /uj/, /ej/, /aw/, /ew/), while Wennergren regards only the latter two as diphthongs" - en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto_phonology

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](https://soundcloud.com/user-345590291/1a-1) is [John Wells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_C._Wells) pronouncing the words *feŭda*, *neŭtrala* and *Eŭropo* in the [pronounciation CD of the EAB](http://www.esperanto.org.uk/education/proncd_track2.html).

Comment: Thanks. John Wells considered Eŭ as a diphthong whereas many other early esperantists did not. This link is very helpful.

Comment: John Wells, who is still alive today and who was born two or three decades after Zamenhof's death, should probably not be considered an "early Esperantist."

Comment: John Wells does not consider the Esperanto diphthongs to be separate phonemes like the diphthongs in English. So when he calls them "diphthongs", this is just his term for a combination of a vowel and a semivowel. It does not imply that the semivowel in the diphthong is pronounced differently than if it comes before the vowel in its syllable.

Answer (score 6):

"American Esperantist" has a short video with the common diphtongs. The answer to your question is 34 seconds in. See link.

https://youtu.be/iEnWq3hSBUA?t=34s

Answer (score 2):

Tony, you seem to have some odd ideas about phonetics.

You say that "-aj" in Esperanto isn't pronounced like [a] followed by [j], but that *is* exactly how it's pronounced.

You claim that "early esperantists did not consider *eŭ* as a diphthong" — can you share the source of that claim, because I've never heard it before, and it doesn't make any sense to me.

Sorry to appear negative, but I don't think it's helpful to others to let strange assertions go unchallenged on a site that aims to curate the best information for future reference. Hopefully the audio and video links posted above will answer your actual question though.

Comment: Tim - I'm not sure what SE-etiquette requires me to do in this situation (contact you off board, flag the question for not being an answer, leave a comment like this one) - but while I agree with the content of your post, it's not an answer to the question and so would probably be better as a comment on the original question (using the "add a comment" link). There are already similar comments on the original question and on the chosen "accepted answer" in this thread.

Comment: You're quite right, the content I wrote above is a comment on an answer, not an answer in its own right. Not sure I can change it now though.

Comment: @TimMorley Saluton Tim. Thanks for the question. -aj is pronounced as a diphthong, so it is not pronounced like [a] followed by [j]. It sounds like 'eye'. "There are also six historically stable diphthongs: /ai̯/, /oi̯/, /ui̯/, /ei̯/ and /au̯/, /eu̯/. However, some authors such as John C. Wells regard them as vowel + consonant combinations (/aj/, /oj/, /uj/, /ej/, /aw/, /ew/), while Wennergren regards only the latter two as diphthongs" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto_phonology

Comment: @TomasoAlexander Can you copy and past it into a comment so the content is not lost?

Comment: If these details are important, my suggestion would be for someone to make them a new question/answer.

Comment: @Lumo5 OK, there are two completely different "levels" at which this question can be answered: the beginner level, and the PhD-in-phonetics level.

At the beginner level, we just consider "a diphthong" to mean "a vowel sound that glides from one sound to another", and by that definition, it's quite clear that -aj, -ej, -oj, -uj, -aŭ, and -eŭ are diphthongs, and of course that (when pronounced correctly) a, e, i, o, and u are NOT diphthongs. (The fact that "eye" contains "TWO vowels sounds" and not just one is a surprise to many English-speaking beginners!)

Comment: @Lumo5 However, at the PhD-in-phonetics-and-phonology level, you are right that different scholars analyse the phonemes differently, that some consider -aj to be a diphthong while others don't. If you're studying phonology at that level, then you're as qualified as anyone else to make your own judgement, and there's nothing that I can add that google can't already find for you.